# boto3 s3 initialized session return credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am facing something similar to [How to load file from custom hosted Minio s3 bucket into pandas using s3 URL format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093837/how-to-load-file-from-custom-hosted-minio-s3-bucket-into-pandas-using-s3-url-for)

however, I already have an initialized s3 session (from boto3).
How can I get the credentials returned from it to feed these directly to pandas?
I.e. how can I extract the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from the initialized boto3 s3 client?

Comment: aren't you the one that is initialising the client with the creds? initialise pandas in the same way? can you show some code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [session.get_credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.get_credentials)

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials.access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials.secret_key
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = credentials.token
```

If you only have access to boto client (like the S3 client), you can find the credentials hidden here:

```py
client = boto3.client("s3")

client._request_signer._credentials.access_key
client._request_signer._credentials.secret_key
client._request_signer._credentials.token
```

---

If you don't want to handle credentials (I assume you're using the SSO here), you can load the S3 object directly with pandas: `pd.read_csv(s3_client.get_object(Bucket='Bucket', Key ='FileName').get('Body'))`

Comment: Thanks. What you are suggesting is an exciting option. But for now, I think I want to keep using the path (with the extra options) as this is more generic. However, `session.meta.client` is the object I am dealing with (and not `session`). How would I need to modify the parameter accordingly for this type?

Comment: I edited my answer with an example with a S3 client, hope this one helps